# ffmpeg not converting an mp3 on OSX. Homebrew installed. Encoder (codec mp3) not found for output stream #0:0

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, mp3

Ok, did the standard hoembrew install for ffmpeg.

All looks cool, i'm guessing that has to include the mpeg codec, yet I keep getting a 0 byte file and the error message:

Encoder (codec mp3) not found for output stream #0:0

Help most appreciated.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -b:a 48k -ar 16000 output.mp3
ffmpeg version 3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
configuration:
libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
[mp3 @ 0x7ff05a010600] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 626.
Input #0, mp3, from 'input.mp3':
Metadata:
title           : Allegro from Duet in C Major
Duration: 00:00:59.56, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 192 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : LAME3.96r
Output #0, mp3, to 'output.mp3':
Metadata:
title           : Allegro from Duet in C Major
Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 0 channels, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (native) -> ? (?))

Encoder (codec mp3) not found for output stream #0:0
```

Comment: -acodec libmp3lame

Comment: You need a build with a MP3 encoder linked. Shouldn't need to specify encoder in this case since ffmpeg assumes it from output format.

Answer (score 1):

This ended up working: brew install --use-clang --HEAD ffmpeg